# Digital Ocean VPC Droplets unable to ssh to each other

Tags: security, networking, ssh, terraform, firewall

I have created a VPC containing 4 droplets: a Bastion which only allows ssh from a single IP, a public web server, a private CMS to feed the public web server, and a secure data store that is encrypted at rest. I have been working on the firewall rules to allow all droplets within the VPC to speak to each other (ssh, 443), and have been completely unsuccessful.

I have a firewall that allows ssh into the Bastion from our VPN IP - this works perfectly. The idea is to ssh into the Bastion then into the other droplets.

There is one ssh key, which is added to authorized_keys for each droplet.

Here is my terraform for the firewall:

```
resource "digitalocean_firewall" "secure_network" {
    name = "secure-network"

    droplet_ids = [digitalocean_droplet.www-sds.id, digitalocean_droplet.www-fe.id, digitalocean_droplet.www-cms.id]

    inbound_rule {
        protocol = "tcp"
        port_range = "22"
        source_addresses = [digitalocean_droplet.bastion.ipv4_address_private]
    }

    outbound_rule {
        protocol = "icmp"
        destination_addresses = ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    }
    outbound_rule {
        protocol = "tcp"
        port_range = "1-65535"
        destination_addresses = ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    }
    outbound_rule {
        protocol = "udp"
        port_range = "1-65535"
        destination_addresses = ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    }

}

resource "digitalocean_firewall" "vpn-only-access" {
    name = "vpn-only-access"
    
    droplet_ids = [digitalocean_droplet.bastion.id]
    
    inbound_rule {
        protocol = "tcp"
        port_range = "22"
        source_addresses = ["159.89.140.157"]
    }
}

resource "digitalocean_firewall" "public-access" {
    name = "public-access"
    droplet_ids = [digitalocean_droplet.www-fe.id]

    inbound_rule {
        protocol = "tcp"
        port_range = "443"
        source_addresses = [digitalocean_droplet.www-fe.ipv4_address]
    }

    inbound_rule {
        protocol = "tcp"
        port_range = "80"
        source_addresses = [digitalocean_droplet.www-fe.ipv4_address]
    }
}
```